# How to set viewcontroller of UITabbarItem to default viewcontroller when switching tabs?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController`. It has `4 tabBarItem`.

1. Suppose I'm at `1st tabBarItem` `defaultViewController(1)` and I
   went to another `ViewController(2)` which is shown after some
   *actions* in first `defaultViewController(1)`.
2. Then I switched to `2nd tabBarItem` `defaultViewcontroller(2)`.
3. Again I switched back to `1st tabBarItem`, it shows `ViewController(2)`.

   I want to show `defaultViewController(1)`. How can I achieve this using `swift 4`.

`defaultViewController(1)` and `defaultViewController(2)` are the default `ViewController` for 1st and 2nd `TabBarItem` respectively.***

Answer (score 1):

Extend a subclass of `UITabbarController` and use it as your tabbar's class. In that implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, `didSelect` and use `popToRootViewController` to pop to your `defaultViewController`.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController){

    if viewController is UINavigationController {
        //when you have `UINavigationController`
        let rootNavigationController = viewController as! UINavigationController
        rootNavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    } else {
        //when you don't have `UINavigationController` then dismiss all viewcontroller that was presented.
        let rootViewController = viewController
        if rootViewController.presentingViewController != nil {
            rootViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** add `self.delegate = self` to conform the protocol inside `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I'd created TabBarController extending UITabbarController, but I'm not being able to implement "didSelect viewController" function. Only "didSelect item" function is available.

Comment: make sure you have adopt UITabBarControllerDelegate in the extended class like  `CustomToolbarViewController : UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate` then you can be able to use  `didSelect viewController `

Comment: I've adopted the delegate but didselect function is not getting called. Do i need to asign delegate to self in viewdidload()?

Comment: you have to Conform to protocol, just write `self.delegate = self` inside `viewDidLoad`, that'll work

Comment: thank you  Arnab sir for your help. 
I'm new to iOS. Would you mind recommending me the topics that need to be known as an iOS developer.

Comment: Happy that it helped... you should know all the basic things first while learning iOS... try to understand view life cycle, app life cycle, tableView, collectionView and other UIs, delegation and nsnotification and other related things... There are few good tutorials available https://www.raywenderlich.com/ and https://www.appcoda.com/

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have *UINavigationController* inside each tab of *UITabBarController*, and **defaultViewController(1)** is the rootViewController of your first tab, inside that there is a button that navigate to **ViewController(2)**.

For this first of all, let's create generic solution. Create **UIApplication** Extension like this,

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

Implement *UITabBarControllerDelegate* in *AppDelegate* and do below code,

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0 {
        UIApplication.topViewController()?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
}
```

In above code, I have taken *tabBarController.selectedIndex* to 0, you can make it different depending on your requirement.

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But the function didselect is not getting called. Should i asign delegate to self in app  delegate?

Comment: Yes you can do it, implement UITabBarController Delegate in AppDelegate and check